# How to set priority for columns and sort the results by that priority?

Tags: mysql, sorting, full-text-search, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
| id |   title |           content             |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
| 1  |  hello  |  how are you?                 |
| 2  |  you    |  it is  content2              |
| 3  |  what   |  hello is a word for greating |
| 4  |  mouse  |  it is content4               |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Well, I want to give a more priority to `title` than `content`. I mean is, I want to show all result from `title` column (in first) and then show all results from `content` column (in second). Also here is my query:

```
select * from mytable where match(title, content) against($word);
```

Also here is two examples:

**Example1:**

```
$word = 'you';
```

I want this output: (focus on the sort)

```
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
| id |   title |           content             |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
| 2  |  you    |  it is  content2              |
| 1  |  hello  |  how are you?                 |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
```

**Example2:**

```
$word = 'hello';
```

I want this output: (focus on the sort)

```
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
| id |   title |           content             |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
| 1  |  hello  |  how are you?                 |
| 3  |  what   |  hello is a word for greating |
+----+---------+-------------------------------+
```

I emphasize again, I want all result from column of `title` and after it all results from from column of `content`. Is there any solution?

Comment: Why not just order by the columns in one select by a specific value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all you need to do is a conditional order by with a CASE and a match off of the word. Here is an example to get you going

```
SELECT title, content
FROM tablename
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN title LIKE '%you%' THEN 1
    WHEN content LIKE '%you%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END;
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c6cd/1)

Answer (score 0):

Run 2 separate queries against the 2 columns and combine them with union into single resultset:

```
select * from mytable where match(title) against($word);
union distinct
select * from mytable where match(content) against($word);
```

EDIT:

If you do not like the union approach, then create 3 fulltext indexes, onne on title, one on content, and one one the co bination of the 2. Then use the following approach:

```
SELECT title, content,
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ($word) AS c1,
  MATCH (content) AGAINST ($word) AS c2
FROM tablename
WHERE MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ($word)
ORDER BY IF(c1> 0,1,0)
```

The combined index would be used for searching, while the individual indexes would be used to produce the weighting. However, if a word is found too many times, its weight may be reduced to 0.

Comment: Yeah seems correct, but actually it is not optimized. Using  two separated `select` clause just for *sorting* ... In my opinion not worth.

Answer (score -1):

seems like your almost there.  How about:

```
select * from mytable where match(title) against($word);
union
select * from mytable where match(content) against($word);
```